# SiteEdit 2009 SP2 configuration: how to disable 'Add component' menu item

Tags: configuration, siteedit-2009

I'm trying to customize the SiteEdit menu bar and component toolbar, enabling only inline editing and publishing. I can enable/disable just about any of the buttons successfully, except the one called 'Add component', the one that has a submenu item. 
Here is my current config section:

```
...
    <Page Visible="true">
      <Edit Visible="false" />
      <AddNew Visible="false" />
      <Publish Visible="true" />
      <Unpublish Visible="true" />
      <Localize Visible="false" />
      <Unlocalize Visible="false" />
    </Page>
    <Component Visible="true">
      <Edit Visible="false" />
      <EditParent Visible="false" />
      <AddNew Visible="false" />
      <AddExisting Visible="false" />
      <ChangeTemplate Visible="false" />
      <Remove Visible="true" />
      <Publish Visible="true" />
      <Unpublish Visible="true" />
      <Localize Visible="false" />
      <Unlocalize Visible="false" />
      <StartActivity Visible="false" />
      <FinishActivity Visible="false" />
    </Component>
...
```

If I change the 'AddNew' and 'AddExisting' inside the Component section back into 'true', all is fine...

This is the javascript error I'm getting, in Menu.js on line 50:

```
TypeError: parentMenuItem is undefined
var menuItems = parentMenuItem.Items;
```

Any ideas as to what could cause this?

Comment: These submenu items are dynamically added, since they depend on the page contents. The code in SiteEdit that adds the items, doesn't seem to consider that its parent may be hidden. You might have hit upon a bug there, in which case it is always best to reach out to SDL Tridion's customer support.

Comment: Thanks @FrankvanPuffelen, that was my guess too, just wanted to check first. We'll contact CS then...